# Colored tables and cline/hhline

Tags: tables, rules, colortbl

How to write `\clines` (or `\hhline`) in colored tables so that the color of the cell does not hide the line?

Here are two solutions but neither of them works fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{hhline} 
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document} 

First try with \verb+\cline+

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|c|c|c|} \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Year} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} Country & GOR & UA &  2006 &  2007 &  2008 \\ \hline
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} &  Milton Keynes & 92 & 94 & 96 \\\cline{3-6}
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}South East} & Reading & 58 & 58 & 60 \\\cline{2-6}
\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}England} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} South West &  Bournemouth& 71 & 72 & 73 \\ \hline
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} & Cardiff & 132.1 & 134.2 & 136.7 \\\cline{3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & Newport & 58.7 & $\perp$ & 59.6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}  
\caption{The clines are somehow hidden by the cell color}
\end{figure}    

Second try with \verb+\hhline+

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|c|c|c|} \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Year} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} Country & GOR & UA &  2006 &  2007 &  2008 \\ \hline
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} &  Milton Keynes & 92 & 94 & 96 \\\hhline{~~----}
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}South East} & Reading & 58 & 58 & 60 \\\hhline{~-----}
\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}England} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} South West &  Bournemouth& 71 & 72 & 73 \\ \hline
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} & Cardiff & 132.1 & 134.2 & 136.7 \\ \hhline{~~----} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & Newport & 58.7 & $\perp$ & 59.6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}  
\caption{Now there is a white line where it shouldn't be}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You shouldn't need the `\noalign{\vskip` and the amounts in the fudge factor probably depend on which pdf viewer you use, but sometimes it helps to keep the rules a little bit away from the coloured panels.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{hhline} 
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document} 


\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\small\sf
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|c|c|c|} \hhline{|*6{-}|}\noalign{\vskip.2pt}
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Year} \\ \hhline{|*6{-}|}\noalign{\vskip.2pt}
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} Country & GOR & UA &  2006 &  2007 &  2008 \\ \hhline{|*6{-}|}\noalign{\vskip.2pt}
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} &  Milton Keynes & 92 & 94 & 96 \\\hhline{|*2{>{\arrayrulecolor[gray]{.8}}-}>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|*4{-}|}
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}South East} & Reading & 58 & 58 & 60 \\\hhline{|*1{>{\arrayrulecolor[gray]{.8}}-}*5{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}|}
\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}England} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} South West &  Bournemouth& 71 & 72 & 73 \\ \hline
\cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} & Cardiff & 132.1 & 134.2 & 136.7 \\ \hhline{|*2{>{\arrayrulecolor[gray]{.8}}-}*4{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}|}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & Newport & 58.7 & $\perp$ & 59.6 \\ \hhline{|*6{-}|}
\end{tabular}  
\caption{Now there is a white line where it shouldn't be}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: David has added the problem and the solution to the `colortbl` package documentation (see section _Less fun with_ `\cline`).

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work, for both vertical and horizontal lines:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &  \cellcolor[gray]{.9}51,6\%  &  \cellcolor[gray]{.9}49\% & 49\% \\
    \hhline{~~|~|~~|}
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  & 49\% & 49\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &  \cellcolor[gray]{.9}51,6\%  &  \cellcolor[gray]{.9}49\% & 49\% \\
    \hhline{~~|-|-~|}
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  & 49\% & 49\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools which have been designed to address that problem.

Form your example with `\cline`, if you load `nicematrix`, replace `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` and you use the key `colortbl-like`, you have directly the expected output.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
 \usepackage{nicematrix}
 \usepackage{multirow}

 \begin{document} 

 \begin{figure}[hbt]
 \centering
 \small\sffamily
 \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|c|c|c|}[colortbl-like] \hline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Year} \\ \hline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} Country & GOR & UA &  2006 &  2007 &  2008 \\ \hline
 \cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} &  Milton Keynes & 92 & 94 & 96 \\\cline{3-6}
 \cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}South East} & Reading & 58 & 58 & 60 \\\cline{2-6}
 \multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}England} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} South West &  Bournemouth& 71 & 72 & 73 \\ \hline
 \cellcolor[gray]{.8} & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} & Cardiff & 132.1 & 134.2 & 136.7 \\\cline{3-6} 
 \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}Wales} & Newport & 58.7 & $\perp$ & 59.6 \\ \hline
 \end{NiceTabular}  
 \end{figure}    

 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

However, always with `{NiceTabular}` and its tools, I would suggest the following code which is simpler (with the same output).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\small\sffamily
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines] 
\CodeBefore
  \rectanglecolor[gray]{0.8}{1-1}{2-6}
  \rectanglecolor[gray]{0.8}{3-1}{7-3}
\Body
            &             &                & \Block{1-3}{Year}     \\ 
    Country & GOR         & UA             &  2006 &  2007 &  2008 \\ 
    \Block{3-1}{England}
            & \Block{2-1}{South East}    
                          &  Milton Keynes & 92    &  94   & 96    \\
            &             & Reading        & 58    &  58   & 60    \\
            &  South West & Bournemouth    & 71    & 72    & 73    \\ 
    \Block{2-1}{Wales}
            & \Block{2-1}{Wales} 
                          & Cardiff        & 132.1 & 134.2 & 136.7 \\
            &             & Newport        & 58.7  & $\perp$   & 59.6  \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}  
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```